# How to check the current screen dimensions in python / Gtk 3.0 without deprecation warnings?

Tags: python, linux, gtk3, pygobject

I need to know dimensions (exactly: height) of the screen below the current Gtk.Window.The most frequently recommended method:

```py
window = Gtk.Window()
screen = window.get_screen()
h = screen.height()
```

does the job, but gives me `DeprecationWarning: Gdk.Screen.height is deprecated`, and is likely to stop working sooner or later. I wouldn't like to add any new dependencies, so [this cool cheat sheet](http://lexxyfox.blogspot.com/2015/02/get-screen-dimensions-in-python.html) doesn't help.

My code is expected to work on Linux w/ multi-headed setups, and this must be the height of the current screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More detailed background: the program I'm working on is a wallpaper manager. I want the (floating) window to use all the possible space vertically, and leave some space on both sides, to watch the background change.

Having no reasonable solution, I decided to follow [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/153968/407666).

```py
def check_height_and_start(window):
    w, h = window.get_size()
    window.destroy()

    if common.sway or common.env['wm'] == "i3":
        h = h * 0.95

    app = GUI(h)



def main():
    (...)
    w = Gtk.Window() # actually I derived from Gtk.Window to make the window transparent

    if common.sway or common.env['wm'] == "i3":
        w.fullscreen()  # .maximize() doesn't work as expected on sway
    else:
        w.maximize()

    w.present()
    GLib.timeout_add(delay_ms, check_height_and_start, w)
    Gtk.main()
```

This way the window height does not include panels, if any. Unfortunately it doesn't work on tiling window window managers, so I had to use `fullscreen()` instead of `maximize()`, and decrease height arbitrarily.

The `delay_ms` optimal value varies with the hardware speed and WM in use, which is another inconvenience.